# Failed to compile while building the react app - static/css/main.4d62b683.css from Css Minimizer plugin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-css-modules, npm-build

While building the react app currently facing this issues.

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/css/main.4d62b683.css from Css Minimizer plugin
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stz7k.png)

I have checked any error on css. But could not find anything.